# Get an average per month in h2 that is one average regardles of which year or month

Tags: sql, h2

I want to get average quantity of petrol consumed by one truck in a month I was able to do this

```
SELECT t.truckCode,
COALESCE(monthname(orderDate),'Not Announced') as month,
IFNULL (avg(petrolQty),0) as avgPetrolQty
from truck t left join orderz o
on t.truckId = o.truckId
group by t.truckCode, COALESCE(monthname(orderDate),'Not Announced')
order by 1,2
```

and got this result

```
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| TRUCKCODE |     MONTH     | AVGPETROLQTY   |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| BY2004    | January       |           13.0 |
| BY2354    | January       |           33.0 |
| BY2874    | January       |           13.0 |
| BY2994    | Not Announced |            0.0 |
| BY8754    | Not Announced |            0.0 |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
```

These are my tables

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS truck;
CREATE TABLE truck (
  truckId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  truckCode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  purchasedDate timestamp  NOT NULL,
  descriptions VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (truckId)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orderz;
CREATE TABLE orderz (
  orderId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  petrolQty DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  orderDate timestamp NOT NULL,
  truckId INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (orderId),
  FOREIGN KEY (truckId) REFERENCES truck(truckId)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

So the issue is I dont want an average that is dependent on which month or year  because with that i will getting different averages for different months 
I want an average/permonth that speaks for all the the orders a truck has , so what i want is a get by id that shows one average/per month for all the orders the truck has 
**NOTE** Per Month i very important 
Currently what i am working is This I would like to get one average/per month so when i get details of truck including the orders it has made i will also get One average that speaks for all the orders, group by orderDate

This is the result

```
+-----------+---------------------+
| TRUCKCODE | AVG(AVGPETROLQTY)   |
+-----------+---------------------+
| BY2004    |                13.0 |
| BY2874    |                13.0 |
| BY2994    |                 0.0 |
| BY8754    |                 0.0 |
| BY2354    |                33.0 |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Do you want to include the 'Not Announced' as if it was any other month?

Comment: yes i guess if fot a particular truck there is no others yet it should be not anounced

Comment: as you see the table its a one to many so one truck can have many orders , but i should get one average per month for the others , what i was able to do was average that was for different months and in my other sql trial i did for months and year , now i think it should be just one average

Comment: Where do you see March in this example? I see every truck has only a single month. 2354 has only 'January' or am I seeing wrong?

Comment: @TheImpaler yeah its an example and actually 2354 has two months january 2005 and january 2008 so my point is there is going to be many orders of petrol for one truck

Comment: so the average should still be one

Comment: Ah... I see. The query you wrote needs to compute the average by month+year. Then, the query I wrote would be correct. Let me take a look again.

Comment: @TheImpaler Take a look i updated my post so you can understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you almost got it the first time. You need to:

- Add grouping by year/month into your original query, to get average per month.
- Perform a select on the result you already have and group it by truck, surrounding the first query with an extra select:

The resulting complete query is:

```
select truckcode, avg(avgPetrolQty) from (
  SELECT t.truckCode,
  COALESCE(year(orderDate),'Not Announced') as year,
  COALESCE(monthname(orderDate),'Not Announced') as month,
  IFNULL (avg(petrolQty),0) as avgPetrolQty
  from truck t left join orderz o
  on t.truckId = o.truckId
  group by t.truckCode, 
    COALESCE(year(orderDate),'Not Announced'),
    COALESCE(monthname(orderDate),'Not Announced')
) group by truckcode
```

This solution has two `select`, the internal included into the external.

The internal select averages the amount by year/month/truck combination. If a truck has 20 orders in 3 months (Jan 2005, Aug 2005, Jan 2006), the internal query will produce three rows. Each one will show the average amount for each month. Other truck will show up more rows in this query.

Then, taking this intermediate result, the external query averages the rows of each truck into a single one. So, the three "monthly" rows get averaged into a single one for the truck in question. Other trucks will get also a single row in this query.

That's it! Have fun.

Comment: I will update my post with your answer and then ask a question concerning your sql

Comment: I posted my result

Comment: and group by monthname should it be just orderDate so it doesnt give two average when dates are of different months , because  COALESCE(monthname(orderDate) gives januart february march ..

Comment: I added `COALESCE(year(orderDate),'Not Announced') as year,` as an extra column, and also to group by.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error saying group by requires : , Like etc , i tried adding  comma but doesnt help , i am trying to get it to work

Comment: Fixed it. Try again.

Comment: i dont think COALESCE works with numbers because i removed and then it worked

Comment: so i will post it now and you can explain a bit how it works

Comment: can you edit your answer and explain what happens when we have 20 orders for one truck with different dates which might be in different year

Comment: Sure, I'll explain.

Comment: ok i corrected you used Coalesce on year but year return number so it doesnt work